# Is There an Indication in Protocol Stack showing that the End Host is Mobile?

Tags: ip, protocol-theory, layer3, mobile

Suppose you are using the Web from your mobile phone. Is there any indication in the internet backbone, when you look at the traffic that shows that the end host is a mobile device? 
I am sure there are many such indicators in the application layer, but I am more interested in answers about IP protocol. I assume their IPs frequently change as they move, so they may be using reserved IPs or anything that I cannot think of.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An IP address is an IP address, and there is nothing in IP that distinguishes what you are looking for. There is the *[IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml)* that explains all the special-purpose IPv4 address ranges, and *[IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml)* for IPv6. IP really doesn't care about what the host is, only that it is addressed in order to be able to route packets between networks.

Comment: I am sure that you somehow need to know the end-host is a mobile device. Even the application developer should care about it. There must be something indicating this. Is it just the application layer messages? Nothing in TCP or TLS handshake as well?

Comment: "_I am sure that you somehow need to know the end-host is a mobile device._" Why do you think that? Routing knows how to forward packets to the network on which the device is addressed, so there is nothing in IP that needs to know what type of device it is. In fact, it would be a corner case for one host to need to know what type another host is. For example, a web browser and web server do not need to know what type of device the other is, they just communicate via HTML.

Comment: @NinjaBug, I think you may be missing the reason for protocols. Network protocols are the rules by which devices communicate. By following the rules of communication, it doesn't matter what type of device is communicating with what type of device, only that the devices follow the rules. Yes, it matters to an application developer for what type of device an application is created, but it really doesn't matter what device is on the other end of the communication if both devices follow the rules and use standard protocols.

Comment: What about Mobile IP? You can trace it in Internet backbone if you are a ISP right? They basically see that you are a mobile host in this case?

Comment: Mobile IP is something different, where the home network is in contact with and end-device that changes address, and when traffic for the home address of the device comes into the home network, it is forwarded to the current address of the mobile device. There is really no way for a different device to know that this is happening. In any case, Mobile IP has been largely ignored and unused.

Comment: Which is truly unfortunate; Mobile IPv6 is very, very nice.

Comment: Depending on the companies providing cell service in a given country, you can *sometimes* deduce that an IP is probably a mobile device by looking up the IP and seeing that it is allocated to a mobile provider. But this is basically a guess, not something in the protocol.

Comment: @mbrig, that is correct, but it really has nothing to do with the network stack and having something in it that indicates a mobile device, as the question asks. That is really just knowing that a certain range of addresses is assigned to a certain company, and nothing to do with an indicator in a protocol that says that it is a mobile device.

Comment: @RonMaupin I 100% agree (which is why I had the last sentence of my comment). I just wanted to provide a situation where you can use information provided by the protocol to make an informed guess.

Comment: Also, how would you define a mobile device?  An iPad built into a kiosk in a building?  A sever rack-mounted in a semi trailer?